# LaunchOptions in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions are nil after Application will be waked up from location

Tags: ios, swift, location

I did search on the internet, found some people who have the same problem but no one did get any solution yet... So I hope anyone here is the G I am searching for..

1 - I did enable "Location updates" and "background fetch" in Background Modes.

[image]

2 - I did call `locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()` on the right place, I checked this on the way I write and string into my Firebase Database when the app will be waked up after terminating.

3 - I am checking on the right way if there is a location key in launchOptions just like Apple on their documentation, see:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/responding_to_the_launch_of_your_app

[image]

So why is my launchOptions nil? I cannot understand why this happens... Because the App is getting waked up, the mistake cannot be on my locationManager handling..

I found this on stackoverflow but my launchOptions are nil so the code is not getting inside the if... 
[Location update even when app is killed/terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527972/location-update-even-when-app-is-killed-terminated)

Please help.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? I am having the same issue 

Comment: @aledap I notised, that my application was started from background when moving, so it does work but my launch options are always null, so I did save with user defaults a value and by starting I check if this value is true, and run some code depending on this, but this only works because I do only have one reason why it starts from background, if you have more than one, it would be harder to know why the app has been started...

Comment: Same issue with Xcode 15.3 and Simulator 17.4 launchOptions are nil when launching due to big change in simulated location. I'm using SwiftUI lifecycle and `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor` maybe that is stripping the info.

Answer (score 0):

It look like you don't save change in database.
Add log and check what happen.
Database file can be locked if device is locked with passcode. And it can happen with `SignificantLocationChanges`. I hope it link help you - [IOS app unable to access files in background when screen locked with passcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662905/ios-app-unable-to-access-files-in-background-when-screen-locked-with-passcode)

P.S. Also for `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()` you don't need  enable "Location updates", it need for `startUpdatingLocation()`
[startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges needs background location enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748830/startmonitoringsignificantlocationchanges-needs-background-location-enabled)

UPD:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati

> If you start this service and your app is subsequently terminated, the
>   system automatically relaunches the app into the background if a new
>   event arrives. In such a case, the options dictionary passed to the
>   application(*:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) and
>   application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) methods of your app
>   delegate contains the key location to indicate that your app was
>   launched because of a location event. Upon relaunch, you must still
>   configure a location manager object and call this method to continue
>   receiving location events. When you restart location services, the
>   current event is delivered to your delegate immediately. In addition,
>   the location property of your location manager object is populated
>   with the most recent location object even before you start location
>   services.

location should have in youre launchOptions, i recommend just print launchOption in console. And  see it with  (viewable from XCode -> Devices -> {your device} ), what keys are present?

Comment: Thank you, but I don‘t know what you mean, to write into the database works perfectly, just the locationKey Is Not being set when the app wakes up into background mode. And I did read, that this key only will be inside the dictionary if the check box of background modes for location updates is enabled. If I am missunderstanding something, please let me know.
The first line where I put "wokeUp" into my database, is working. Only the if, where I want to create an list with all keys, is failing because there is no key in launchOptions.

Comment: @alarsut i recommend just print launchOption in console. And  see it with (viewable from XCode -> Devices -> {your device} ), what keys are present?

Comment: Could you please contact me? Just write me an email to kochhilfeaticlouddotcom with your skypename or anything you have. I do not getting this working. Logs are not showing and launchOptions are nil. I will add the solution, if we get one, under my post as update marked...